# KML slowness in Google maps

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, kml, geoxml3

I have a KML file of size 2.7MB which I am rendering over world map using Google Maps V3. It works fine but the loading time is very slow (**~8** seconds).

I have this KML file locally stored and I use geoxml3 API to render it.

Is it possible to somehow reduce this KML to around 500KB without loss of data to improve loading time? Or maybe some other way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

KMl indexing is not the ultimate geographic data strand. You can use KMZ format.
http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-techniques-for-minimising-the-size-of-your-KML-files

Comment: I am aware of KMZ file but I could not make it work with geoxml3. Seems like there is ZipFile.complete.js which can be of use with KMZ files, but there is no usage guide or examples for this. Can you please provide some pointers on its use.